# What are the pros and cons of Windows Essential Business Server?

Tags: windows-server-essentials

I just heard about Windows Essential Business Server for the first time yesterday.  We currently have Small Business Server, and were thinking of migrating to the standard server products.  We're approaching the limit on number of mailboxes.

From reading the Microsoft web site, I can't tell whether Essential Business Server is a good idea, or whether they've packaged the standard components together in some novel way that although is supposed to make things easier, results in something harder to keep running reliably.

Has anyone used EBS?  Do you find it delivers on Microsoft's promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question f](https://serverfault.com/questions/33215/windows-essential-business-limitations-experience)or similar answers.

In my experience the SBS and Essentials products have always been a good way for business with limited budgets to get a way in to the enterprise level services of Exchange and SQL etc. SBS in particualar has been refined so that it is a well packaged product that integrates each service well through, rather than just being a collection of different components.

Answer (score 0):

Beware.  Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials (and probably sans R2) will by default upon first time install and set up will create your domain as MYDOMAIN.local.  (MYSERVER is your domain you choose) You cannot choose any other suffix.  i.e. .com, .net, etc.  Once it's done, apparently that's it.  Standard is probably the better route if you need something other than .local.

Comment: Not entirely true. You cannot do it through the wizard, but you can create an answer file to specify the domain suffix.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2830511

Comment: Well there's my answer I have been looking for.  I did stumble across this "answer file" possible solution, but needed clarification it would work on WS2012R2 Essentials first before reinstalling again.  I'll test on a VM to make sure. http://serverfault.com/questions/702674/windows-server-2012-r2-essentials-local-to-com-easy-change-probably-hard-or-n